# Keep the dropdown open always in angular2-multiselect-dropdown

Tags: angular, npm, dropdown, multi-select

I am using angular2-multiselect-dropdown in angular. I am using it in a popup. Now when i click a button, I want the popup to show the dropdown in open mode. I dont want to again select the down arrow in it.

```
      <angular2-multiselect [data]="columns" 
                      [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" 
                      [settings]="settings" 
                      (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
                      (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event)" 
                      (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)" 
                      (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)">
</angular2-multiselect>
```

Comment: did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @rifa I think I did some custom css modifications to the angular multiselect classes to show it as open

Answer (score 0):

You can add a reference template to your angular2-multiselect component.

```
<angular2-multiselect [data]="columns"...  #multiselect>
</angular2-multiselect>
```

And then in your button add this code:

```
<button type="button" (click)="function(); multiselect.click()">Button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks but it didnt help